# How can I select max from a Stream or wait for next if it's empty?

Tags: dart, concurrency, stream

I have a stream of incoming data that I would like to buffer, so when I actually want to process the data I can pick the most suitable one from the buffer based on a *critera*.

If the buffer is empty I want to wait for the first available data from the stream and return with that.

In this example my criteria is *max*:

```
class Repo { 
  final Stream<int> input; 
  List<int> buffer = [];

  Repo(this.input) {
    input.listen((num) => buffer.add(num));
  }

  Future<int> getNext() async {
    if (buffer.isEmpty) {
      await input.isEmpty;
    }
    var max_num = buffer.reduce(max);
    buffer.remove(max_num);
    return max_num;
  }
}
```

My problems with this solution:

- If there are multiple concurrent `getNext` calls waiting for `input.isEmpty`, all of them will continue and they over-consume the buffer.
- `buffer.remove` and `buffer.add` can happen "at the same time" causing inconsistent buffer.

What would be a better solution?

Comment: How could `buffer.remove` and `buffer.add` happen at the same time?

Comment: `buffer.add()` runs async every time, when a new `int` appears on `input`, in the meantime, `getNext` can be called.

Comment: Each Dart isolate is single-threaded.  When the callback to invoke `buffer.add` is executed, since it does not yield with `await`, it cannot be interrupted by `getNext`.  Likewise, once `getNext` is ready to do `buffer.remove`, it cannot be interrupted by the `buffer.add` callback.

Comment: Thanks, then I have just one problem with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that your second problem is actually a problem there as written.  Each Dart isolate is single-threaded. When the stream's listener callback to invoke `buffer.add` is executed, since it is synchronous (it does not yield with `await`), it cannot be interrupted by `getNext`. Likewise, once `getNext` is ready to do `buffer.remove`, it cannot be interrupted by the `buffer.add` callback.

As for the first problem, I *think* that you could make all `getNext` calls wait in a loop:

```dart
  Future<int> getNext() async {
    while (buffer.isEmpty) {
      await input.isEmpty;
    }

    var max_num = buffer.reduce(max);
    buffer.remove(max_num);
    return max_num;
  }
```

When an event is added to the `Stream`, your listener will add an element to `buffer` and should cause one of the first outstanding `getNext` call to break out of the loop and process `buffer`. (And as explained above, since this processing is synchronous, it cannot be interrupted.) Additional outstanding `getNext` calls then will be processed, see that `buffer` is (again) empty, and resume waiting. (What isn't immediately clear to me is if it's *guaranteed* that the `await`s (which are really `Future.then()` callbacks) will complete in order.)

Comment: the first call of `getNext()`  returns with `null`.
the rest of the callers get the _same_ item.  I would like to ensure that when a caller gets the max, then the next/waiting caller gets _next_ biggest number.